# How to listen for local changes in data class object, so remote Firebase document is updated automatically

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, listener

I have a custom data class in Kotlin that is to be synced with Firebase as per the [manual](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

```
data class Data(
    var description: String? = null,
    var user_created_id: String? = null,
    var user_responded_id: String? = null,
    var status: Long? = null,
)
```

That manual provides a way to listen for remote changes in Firebase via adding addSnapshotListener to the Firebase document reference.
However I would like to set up a listener in the opposite way also: when something changes in at least one field in my local data object, the Firebase database should update automatically.
I assume [Delegates.observable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html) should work that way. However, when I add it to the data object, it runs code on listener only after the object is created. After I change its fields, nothing happens...

```
override var data : Data? by Delegates.observable(Data()) { property, oldValue, newValue -> { log("something was changed in the object") }
```

Comment: Why not add the new value directly to Firestore?

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the comment. I created a layer between Firebase and the app logic to get some loose coupling between the database and logic (controller). So I would like all operations to be done on the objects of custom created classes

Answer (score 1):

Right now I can think of the following two ways to implement this.

- Instead of updating the fields, update the entire object with new fields.
  Example: To update the description, you can do:

  ```kotlin
  data?.description = "New description" // won't notify the observer
  OR
  data = data?.copy(description = "Another description") // will notify the observer
  ```

  If you go this way, you can make your fields `val` instead of `var`.
- If you don't need your class to be a data class, use a normal class and override setters for the fields.

  ```kotlin
  class Data(val onDataChange: (Data) -> Unit) {
      var description: String? = null
          set(value) {
              field = value
              onDataChange(this)
          }
      // Similarly for other fields
  }
  ```

  Here, instead of overriding the setter, you could have also used `Delegates.observable` for each field.

If you really want an observer pattern you can adopt one of these two approaches (the first one looks nicer to me).

Comment: Thank you for your response. For the first way - it seems like I can achieve the same via getter and setter. However my goal in the end is to use simple "equals" ("=") operator to assign values: data.description = "my description". Also unfortunately, it seems like I need class to be data class because Firebase automatically map kotlin data class members to collections fields: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects